# libc.so mmap strace

Tags: c, mmap, libc

I am studying for exam tomorrow and I ran across this question:

After we run an executable with strace the following syscalls result regarding standard C lib:

- open("/lib/libc.so.6", "O_RDONLY") = 3
- mmap(NULL, 36803630, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 
  0x7f312ab35000
- mmap(0x7f312aeae000, 20480, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x179000) = 0x7f312aeae000

The question is why does the first syscall of mmap uses PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC and the second one PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE.

Please explain me what happens after each mmap call in detail. I don't understand why a process would need to modify libc (write access).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maps are private (`MAP_PRIVATE`), so nothing is modifying `libc.so`; instead, it's modifying a private (to the process) copy of pages mapped from `libc.so`. This will include the data segment (global variables in libc) as well as the Global Offset Table (GOT) and perhaps other structures involved in relocating the library to a particular address at runtime.

Comment: and why does PROT_EXEC disappears ?

Comment: Data does not need to be executable; it's data, not code. And making writable memory executable is considered a security risk since it expands the class of vulnerabilities that can be elevated to arbitrary-code-execution by allowing the attacker a place to put the code. Many hardened systems don't even allow memory to be mapped with both write an execute permission simultaneously.